# Using structs with generics - Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I'm trying to use generics in inheritance with structs, see.

```
  public class AuditLogEntry : ObjectBase<AuditLogEntry.AuditLogEntryStruct>
    {

        private struct AuditLogEntryStruct
        {
            public int AuditID;
        }
}

 public abstract class ObjectBase<T> 
{
}
```

It won't let me use private for my struct, as it throws the error:
Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'ObjectBaseAuditLogEntry.AuditLogEntryStruct>' is less accessible than class 'AuditLogEntry'.

However I don't really want to make my struct public.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
Alex

**Follow on question:**

Here is what we are trying to do:

```
class AuditLogEntry : ObjectBase<AuditLogEntry.AuditLogEntryStruct>
{
  internal struct AuditLogEntryStruct
        {
            public int AuditID;
}

  public int AuditID
        {
            get
            {
                return udtObject.AuditID;
            }
set{
BeginEdit();
 udtObject.AuditID = value;
        }

}

 class ObjectBase<T>
{
  protected T udtObject;
        protected T udtPreEditObject;

  protected  void BeginEdit()
        {
            if (!IsDirty)
            {
                IsDirty = true;
                udtPreEditObject = udtObject;
            }
        }
}
```

I'm not sure how to achive this within making AuditLogEntryStruct public?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

You can't derive a public class from a generic class when one or more of the type arguments aren't public

The types that any type derives from has to be as accessible as the deriving class, inculding any type parameters given as type arguments to the base class

if you have

```
public class publicClass{}
```

Any class can derive from A however if you changed it to

```
internal class internalClass{}
```

only other internal classes can derive from it.

The same is true if you passed either of the types as a type parameter. The first three below are valid the fourth is not

```
public class A : List<publicClass>{}
internal class B : List<internalClass>{}
internal class C : List<publicClass>{}

//not valid because D has wider accessibility than the close generic type List<internalClass>
public class D : List<internalClass>{}
```

**EDIT**
The language team at some point have had to make a decision whether to make a declaration as yours invalid or make any use of your type that resulted in illegal access to an inaccessible type invalid. In your case there would be several methods returning a type that would be inaccessible to all others than your class and a number of methods taking an argument of a type no other class could provide. So the only objects that would actually be able to use objects of your class would be objects of your class. You can solve that with composition instead of inheritance

```
public class AuditLogEntry
{
        private ObjectBase<AuditLogEntry.AuditLogEntryStruct> _entry;
        private struct AuditLogEntryStruct
        {
            public int AuditID;
        }
}

public abstract class ObjectBase<T> 
{
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any idea what the framework would do if the language compiler tried to expose a public type which used non-public classes within some of its declarations?  I would think it would in fact be useful if the system would simply restrict use of members to code which could access their types.  This would be helpful in at least two cases: (1) A module wants to allow outside code to use its interfaces, but not add new implementations; (2) A module which will only allow internal inheritance wants protected members to use internal types.

Comment: @supercat I haven't tried (and I've tried for the fun of it to do some weird stuff to the CLR) if I were to guess I'd say the CLR wouldn't complain. You can change the type of 'this' to be of a completely different type and get away with it under certain circumstance that changes the behavior this doesn't really change anything and would execute just fine so they might have left it to language to decide those rules for them self

Comment: @RuneFS: I'm curious about such things, because as I said it would seem there are at least two reasonable usage cases for allowing types to expose inner types *to those entities who can use them*, and I don't really see a good basis for disallowing it *unless it would cause problems with the Framework*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
public class Foo : List<Bar>
{
    private struct Bar { }
}


var myFoo = new Foo();
...
var x = myFoo()[0]; // expression on the right side is of type Bar, yet Bar is inaccessible
```

**UPDATE**

What you are trying to achieve doesn't really require generics. You only access your structs inside `ObjectBase<T>` as if they were objects. You might as well change them to `object` and remove generic type altogether.

If you have some more logic that requires some sort of functionality from `AuditLogEntryStruct` to be accessable in `ObjectBase<T>`, you may extract an interface:

```
public interface IStructsWithSomeFunctionality { ...  }
```

make your struct implement it and use it as your type parameter

```
public class AuditLogEntry : ObjectBase<IStructsWithSomeFunctionality> { ... }
```

Comment: The compiler would know the type in the last line but the declaration of x would be illegal.

Comment: That's just an example of why a class with wider accessibility then the type parameter of it's base class introduces inconsistency. Intuition suggests ``myFoo()[0]`` is a legal expression, but then it's type is inaccessable, thus the inconsistency.

Comment: I agree on the point you are trying to make but what you have written is incorrect. if Foo had the following method `object getFirst(){return myFoo()[0];}` you would still have access to the same object the compiler would still need to know the type of the object (and that type is _not_ object but Bar). Again I agree with the example it's the explanation of why the example would be invalid that's well invalid

Comment: In your case the expression seen outside is of type ``object`` as opposed to ``List<T>`` iterator property, which is ``T``. What I was referring to was static, compile-time expression type. Anyway, I'll change the comment.

Comment: it's no different from changing your line of code to `object x = myFoo()[0];` which was my point exactly that the declaration is illegal.

Comment: It's not the declaration, but the inconsistent accessibility that was illegal. Publicly exposing properties of type, that is inaccessible is wrong. Using properties and expecting they're declared type to be accessible is not.